# Prove that the function is constant $f(x)=\arcsin2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}} - 2\arcsin x$

Tags: functions, constants

Prove that this function is constant:
$$f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right) - 2\arcsin x$$

Comment: Derivate it and you find $0$.

Comment: It is constant for $|x|\le\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$, for $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2<|x|\le1$ is not constant, and for $|x|>1$ is undefined.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane yes I know that I should derivate and if the function is 0 then the function is constant, but I have problems to derivate it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Let $x=\sin y$ then $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\dots?$

And $\sin2y=\dots?$

Comment: I need to derivate this function, i'm having trouble while I'm derivating it, then if function is equal with 0 it means that it's constant

Comment: $\arcsin'u=\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$, when $u=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then $u'=2\sqrt{1-x^2}+2x\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}(-2x)=\frac2{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1-x^2+x^2)$